# Laravel Broadcast - Combining multiple middleware (web, auth:api)

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-5.5, laravel-passport, laravel-events

I am using Laravel Event Broadcast and Pusher to utilize websockets both on my API and Web. If I try them individually, both work fine. What I mean is:

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'web']); // this works for my Laravel website

Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'auth:api']); // this works for my api
```

However, if I want to use both at the same time like this:

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'web']]); // doesn't work
```

... it crashes for both, which I suspect that it is assuming I am trying to enable for both `auth:api && web` middlewares.

Is there a way to use an OR kind of statement for this (`auth::api || 'web')`? What if I want to use both at the same time and if it passes one middleware, it bypasses the middleware.

<sub>Please note that I am using Laravel Passport for my api.</sub>

---

Or is there a way to combine and creating a mixed middleware for both (which will essentially check for either api or web)? So I can use something like this maybe:

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'broadcast']); // or auth:broadcast
```

---

**Update:**

As far as I understand, if I create a new Middleware called `broadcast`, I can do:

```
class BroadcastMiddleware() {

  public function handle() {
    $web = Auth::guard('web')->user();
    if ($web) {
        return response()->json($web);
    }

    $api = Auth::guard('api')->user();
    if ($api) {
        return response()->json($api);
    }
    return response()->json('Unauthorized.', 500);
  }
}
```

But then how do I change `/broadcasting/auth` route? If I try this:

```
Route::post('/realtime/auth', function(){
    return true;
})->middleware('broadcast');
```

This returns the user object info, however instead, it should return something like: `auth:"374f7ff42b7da877aa35:c29addedec281b418331a61dc3cfc74da8b108222565fa4924a8..."`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not just use something like this in the BroadcastServiceProvider? This creates two separate endpoints with separate middleware assigned.

```
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'web']);

    Broadcast::routes(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'api']);
```

Comment: Great solution, used this myself. Although I had to specify the middleware as 'auth:api' to get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Sledmore glad I could help!

Comment: This seems waaaay more elegant than my solution. I didn't try it myself personally just yet though.

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured out how to do it.

*I am not sure if it is the best way of achieving this, and I'd highly appreciate any improvements*.

How I achieved is created a new middleware for 'web' and left the other one as it it. Here are the steps.

1) In 'BroadcastServiceProvider', left only `auth:api` guard for `Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'auth:api']);`.

This way, Laravel's `auth:api` method for authenticating broadcasting works as expected.

2) Created a middleware called "Broadcast" and mapped it in Kernel.php like so:

`'broadcast' => \App\Http\Middleware\Broadcast::class`

and the `Broadcast.php` middleware looks like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $web = Auth::guard('web')->user();
    if ($web) {
        return response()->json(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::auth($request));
    }

    return response()->json('Unauthorized.', 500);
}
```

3) Created a unique route other than Laravel's /broadcasting/auth in my routes>web.php

```
Route::post('/guard/broadcast/auth', function(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request $req){
    return true;
})->middleware('broadcast');
```

4) And then only on my blade, I use it like so:

```
<script>

let pusher = new Pusher("{{ env('PUSHER_APP_KEY') }}", {
    cluster: 'us2',
    encrypted: true,
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
        }
    },
    authEndpoint: '{{ env('APP_URL') }}' + '/guard/broadcast/auth',
});

let channel = pusher.subscribe('private-channel.{{ Auth::user()->id }}');

channel.bind('my-event', addMessage);

function addMessage(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm preferable just using middleware that extends to both `auth:api` and `web` middlewares.

like what I posted in here: https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server/issues/266#issuecomment-365599129. So, I just maintenance 1 middleware if I wanted to change it in the future

Comment: But, this approach didn't return me `auth:"374f7ff42b7da877aa35:c29addedec281b418331a61dc3cfc74da8b108222565fa4924a8..."` which is what the authenticator needs

Answer (score 0):

BroadcastServiceProvider

```
if (request()->hasHeader('authorization')){
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'auth:api']);
} else {
    Broadcast::routes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use prefix approach for achieve multiple authorization types.
If you will use a middleware -  it is just redundant middleware.
If you will use if block (as on a code snippet below): you will face problem with routes caching, it will return 403 error becuase Laravel should cache a route with a set of middlewares.

```
if (request()->hasHeader('authorization')){
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'auth:api']);
} else {
    Broadcast::routes();
}
```

You even may register separate service providers for web and api to split responsibilities and it will work.
For Web

```
class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['web']);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

And for Api

```
class ApiBroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => ['auth:api']]);

        require base_path('routes/dam-channels.php');
    }
}
```